# improve CNN model accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

We have got some train valid and test data to create as homework CNN1D and to compare results with another model to get the exam marks
I tried with this model however I'm getting 84.18 accuracy Vs 84.58 for the competitor model. my classmates got also the same model as mine and they could improve it to get 85.20% as accuracy. Im just authorized to change the hyper parameters or to add/modify/delete some layers v after the `fusion = concate()`

Can anyone please help me improve this

```
def CNN1D ()
    n_filters=256,
    dropout_rate = 0.4
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', name="conv1_", activation="relu")
    Dropout1 = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, name="dropOut1_")
    conv2 = Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', name="conv2_", activation="relu")
    Dropout2 = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, name="dropOut2_")
    conv3 = Conv1D(filters=n_filters*2, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', name="conv3_", activation="relu")
    Dropout3 = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, name="dropOut3_")
    conv4 = Conv1D(filters=n_filters*2, kernel_size=1, padding='valid', name="conv4_", activation="relu")
    Dropout4 = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate,name="dropOut4_")
    globPool = GlobalAveragePooling1D()

    def TwoBranchModel():
    num_units=256

      branch1 = CNN1D()
      branch2 = CNN1D() 
      fusion = concate()
      out = tf.keras.Sequential([
                Dense(num_units,activation='relu'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                Dense(n_classes,activation='softmax')
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try playing with the following

1. decrease the dropout percentage
2. Try playing with BatchNormalisation hyperparameters. See here: https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/ and adjust the momentum. Also remove the BN layer and see the accuracy.

I am not sure if you can change the below (as per your constraint)

3. change globalpoolaverage to maxpool
4. your filter size seems to be constant, it is good idea if start increasing your number of filters. For example start with 32, 64, 128 and so on..
5. remove some dropout layers.